# Chip to read MIFARE Classic EV1 1K MF1S50YYX_V1cards

Tags: rfid, mifare, nxp-microcontroller

I wanted to develop a micro-controller based Embedded board using which I can read MIFARE Classic MF1S50YYX based cards. Which chips should I interface with microcontroller to read and write MIFARE Classic MF1S50YYX based cards?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of PCD chips from various manufacturer for reading PICC devices ( like Mifare classic MF1S50 cards and so) from NXP itself, ST, TI, etc.
If you just intended to interact with Mifare classic cards I recommend MFRC522 as it's cheap and there are a lot of economical minimum board and source codes for it.
But if you intended to do more serious job like developing a commercial product and there are possible situation to add NFC support or reading distance and power is a factor also I recommend PN5180.
Also another option is PN7462, which a cortex M0+ MCU is integrated with PCD chip inside a same IC Package.